# Accessing an Android Serial Port the Same Way As on Linux

Tags: android

I would like to access a serial port connected to an Android Device.  I can access the port from the Android APIs fine.  I compiled the cdc-acm module and loaded it into the kernel.  When I plug in the serial devices, the kernel recognizes it.

```
<6>[  128.283910] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
<6>[  128.289574] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB    modems and ISDN adapters
<6>[  138.115155] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 4
<6>[  140.913303] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
<6>[  141.048377] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=0042
<6>[  141.055330] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=220
<6>[  141.062824] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Arduino (www.arduino.cc)
<6>[  141.068617] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 85439313230351706291
<6>[  141.078802] cdc_acm 1-1.4:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

I then add the device
   mknod /dev/ttyACM0 c 166 0

However, when I access the /dev/ttyACM0 from a C program, I get

No such device or address

Is the Android kernel preventing character drivers from accessing the USB stack?  If so, can someone point me to where in the kernel this occurs.  Also if there is a switch to turn it on/off.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at `/dev/ttyACM0` **before** the `mknod`?

Comment: There is no /dev/ttyACM0 before the mknod.

Comment: Fine, my suspicion was some udev interaction. Now try `mknod /dev/ttyACM0 c 188 0` to make sure we cover the correct major.

Comment: I looked in the driver to check the Major Number, 166 is correct.  I also don't think Android uses udev.  Thanks!